# Add additional variables as exog in SARIMAX time series forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima, forecast

Lets say I need to forecast the TPV/sales per month which would be affected by Black Friday, Cyber Monday, Christmas and other campaigns..
I add in all these 4 variables in the dataframe and include it in 'exog' like below

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(Y,order=param,seasonal_order=param_seasonal,exog=exog_var,enforce_stationarity=False,enforce_invertibility=False)

My question is How do we add the values for these 4 exog variables for future dates??
If I add these 4 variables and leave the 'TPV/sales' column blank..
It does not predict for those time periods and output 'nan'

Please help me understand how to add exog variables for future dates and how to forecast the Y variable?

Answer (score 2):

The way statsmodels structures analysis is in the following steps:

1. Create a model to describe your data, e.g.:

   ```
   mod = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(endog_training, order=(1, 0, 0), exog=exog_training)
   ```
2. Fit the parameters of your model, e.g.:

   ```
   res = mod.fit()
   ```
3. Perform post-estimation analysis.

   a. For example, you might want to examine the fitted parameters, summary output, etc, e.g.:

   ```
   print(res.summary())
   ```

   b. Or, as in your case, you might want to perform out-of-sample forecasting, e.g.:

   ```
   forecast = res.forecast(nsteps, exog=exog_test)
   ```

So you only want to include your training data in the model construction step. When you want to forecast new periods with the out-of-sample `exog` values, you do that using the `forecast` method of the results object.